# How to retrieve every file in the Internal Storage?

Tags: java, android, file

In Android, assuming that I have files in "/data/data/package.name/", without knowing the names or how many files exist, what is the best way to retrieve/iterate them all?
Also, the name is numerical only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to list all of the files in the directory, and (possibly) recurse if a file is a directory.

You can find how to do this at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997364/android-how-to-get-directory-listing).

Copy-pasted:

```
File f = new File("/data/data/package.name/");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // is directory; recurse?
    } else {
        doLogicFor(inFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Some times when I read the documentation, I don't really understand its usage. I guess this is one of the cases.