# How to show list of all folders in android file system specially SD card

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application I want to display all folders on an SD card in a listview and need functionality such that if a user clicks on a folder it will show its sub-directories.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
File f = new File(path);
File[] files = f.listFiles();
for (File inFile : files) {
    if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
        // is directory
    }
}
```

This will return you the list of folders in your path.
From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6997422/2065418