# How to show list all folders not files in path

Tags: android

I am developer and I want list All folders in path in file manager but show all files and folders in method file.list() please help me to show all folders not files in path.

```
   File file = new File("Path");

    if(file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
        String[] list = file.list();
        int len = list.length;

        /* add files/folder to arraylist depending on hidden status */
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(list[i].toString().charAt(0) != '.')
            mDirContent.add(list[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's about this [android, how to get directory listing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997364/android-how-to-get-directory-listing)

Shortly, you need to use File.listFiles() method and then check if an item is a directory by method File.isDirectory().