# How do I access a "child" folder under a file?

Tags: android, storage, android-external-storage, android-storage

I need to access all files inside a folder which is inside the downloads folder.

I can get the files in the downloads folder like this `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` and that return a `File`.

How do I get the same but for the folder `mCustomFolder`?

Comment: You did not show how you access all files in that download folder.

Comment: I believe this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531063/764624

Comment: `How do I access a “child” folder under a file?` You mean `How do I access a “child” folder under a folder?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be simple I guess. Try this.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/someFolder");

for(File f : files){
   //access your all files and folders here inside the given folder

}
```

Learn more about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997364/android-how-to-get-directory-listing) on how to access external storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
File subDir = new File(
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
    "/mCustomFolder/");
File[] files = subDir.listFiles();
for (File f : files) {
    // f is your file
}
```